# Is it possible to have a route parameter in the middle of a route string in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.7

Like the title says: Is it possible to have a route parameter in the middle of a string in my route in Laravel 5.7?

My route is defined as so:

```
Route::get('/foos/foo-{bar}-baz', function () {
    return 'something';
}
->where('bar', '*+'), 
->middleware(['web', MyMiddleware::class]);
```

I am wanting to access this parameter in the `MyMiddleware` class but it always returns null, unless I define my route as `'/foo/{bar}/baz'`

I've tried a number of different regex combinations to no avail.

Comment: Can you update the question and show the regex you've used in your route file for the `bar`?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* define it as (although the other answers seem to suggest you shouldn't need to)

```
Route::get("/foos/{foo-bar-baz}", function($fooBarBaz){
  return "something";
});
```

Essentially, anything after `/foos/` would be available as `$fooBarBaz`. If `$fooBarBaz` contained something like `"foo-bar-baz"`, you could simply explode it on `-` and access the second part of the parameter:

```
$parts = explode("-", $fooBarBaz);
// do something with $parts[1]
```

It should also be possible to regex-constrain the parameter to ensure it's in a specific format, such as `foo-[a-zA-z]-baz`, etc.

Comment: I may go this route if I can't get it to work the other ways. Thanks for the response.

Comment: No worries. Just make sure it doesn't conflict with other routes. Generally, you'd put this at the bottom of your routes file, or the bottom of a `Route::group()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the regex of the `bar` parameter:

```
Route::get('/foos/foo-{bar}-baz', function () {
    return 'something';
})
->where('bar', '[a-z0-9-]+')
->middleware(['web', MyMiddleware::class]);
```

If I then visit `/foos/foo-hello-world-baz` on Chrome after, and perform a `dd($request->bar);` in my middleware, I receive the following output:

```
hello-world
```

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Comment: I did define the regex. I just didn't include it... Still `null` unfortunately.

Comment: @Brandon What is the regex that you've defined? I tried with the regex above and I can retrieve the parameter just fine with `$request->bar`.

Comment: `->where('bar', '*+')`, `->where('bar', '[\w]+')`, `->where('bar', '[\w-]+')`, among others.

Comment: @Brandon I just tried with `->where('bar', '[\w-]+')` and it is still working fine. What is the url you are using in your browser?

Comment: `mysite.test/foos/foo-xyz-baz` where `xyz` is any characters. All of my other routes in the entire application are working.

Comment: @Brandon You'd have to show more because there must be something else that's causing it to not work. This will work on a fresh Laravel install.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it exactly as you shown, I just tested and it works as expected.

First of all, register your middleware in the `app\Http\Kernel.php` file.

Then in the middleware handle method you can get the `bar` value as such:

```
$request->route('bar');
```

I used this for testing:

```
Route::get('/foos/foo-{bar}-baz', function($bar) {
   dd($bar);
})->middleware(['mym' => function($request, $handle) {
    dd($request->route('bar'), 'Test within middleware');
}]);
```

Given your middleware both returned the value for me again, can you try adding full namespace to the route:

```
->middleware(['web', \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class]);
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I keep getting `null` no matter what in my middleware.

Comment: Can you please show the content of your middleware? I gave you my code that I use above, you can try that one and make sure you don't use something different.

Comment: What url have you tested this with? It should return a 404.

Comment: @Brandon please check my edit. I tested again. It works for me

Comment: Try just with your custom middleware in case something gets stripped in the other middleware, I really don't know what else to say. I am testing it myself on my project and it does work.